# Html5 .mp4 video freezes after few seconds in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, video

I am playing .mp4 video file in google chrome at playrate of 0.0625. Video play perfectly, but freezes after few seconds. I tried disabling adblock, tries to find resources for chrome freezing issue. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/0jUI-nrKR4c;context-place=topicsearchin/youtube/category$3Awatching-videos%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false here. But unable to solve the problem.

Here is my video tag code.

```
<video id="video" class="vid"  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data="videoGraph0"  width="100%" >
<source src="../Api/Media/Play?f=' + path1 + '" />
</video>
```

Comment: No one can't even give you hint, not to mention an answer, without any code, a link to video file that does not work or any other kind of example, that reproduces the failure.

Comment: Have you tried this on another PC? Maybe your video card driver has some issues with such a video type or your Chrome installation is broken somehow.